# Apply a CSS style to a child span with a dynamic id on hover of a parent div with a dynamic id

Tags: html, css

I have multiple parent divs that each contain multiple child spans.  Only a select one of these spans do I want to hide upon hovering of the parent div.  Currently, I am grabbing all of the parent divs like this:

```
div[id*=timeline_record_container]
```

Each of these parent divs contains the string `timeline_record_container` followed by a unique and dynamic ID.  Then I am doing something similar with it's children:

```
span[id*=timeline_record_default_icons]
```

Where they all have the string `timeline_record_default_icons` followed by a unique/dynamic ID as well. Adding both of these selectors together and the hover event gives me something like this:

```
div[id*=timeline_record_container]:hover > span[id*=timeline_record_default_icons] {
    display: none;
}
```

My thought here is on hover of `timeline_record_container` divs, find the `timeline_record_default_icons` one and set it to `display: none`.  However this isn't working, am I ordering these wrong?

Edit: I added the HTML.  The highlighted span is what I want to hide inside of the top level div in the image.
[image: Picture of HTML]

Comment: Your HTML. Please hand it over.

Comment: Just added the HTML in an image.  I updated the question to reflect the HTML better.  I was trying to simplify it before the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot, the `span` you're targeting to hide is not an immediate child of `div[id*=timeline_record_container]`.

Consider the following snippet:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="brat">
    <span class="target">The target</span>
  <div>
</div>
```

In the above snippet, to access target, you could write:

```css
.parent .target {
  …
}
```

But not:

```css
.parent > .target {
  …
}
```

You could access `.brat` as an immediate child, because it lives on the first nesting level below the `.parent` node.

```css
.parent > .brat {
  …
}
```

So, back to your example. I think simply removing the `>` symbol before the `span` should do the trick.

```css
div[id*=timeline_record_container]:hover span[id*=timeline_record_default_icons] {
    display: none;
}
```